# Python: rstrip('\n') is not stripping the \n in my list

Tags: python, file

I split a file into its lines using `.readLines()` but for some reason after I create the list and use `line.rstrip('\n')` there is still `'\n'` at the end of my items.

```
lines = readFile.readlines()

for line in lines :
    line.rstrip('\n')

if lines[127] == "<th>FID</th>" :
    print(lines[127] + "is equal to <th>FID</th>")
else :
    print(lines[127] + "is not equal to <th>FID</th>")
```

I tried to strip using

```
line.rstrip('\n')
```

But after the comparison it still outputs <kbd>it is not equal</kbd>.

Comment: You meant to write: `lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in readFile.readlines()]` to actually have an effect. Where you wrote: `line.rstrip('\n')`  <--- this has no effect.

Comment: 5 seconds python doc search : https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip specifically specifies `Return a copy of the string with trailing characters removed.`

Comment: `lines = readFile.read().splitlines()` would do just fine. [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines). No need to loop then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rstrip()` method returns a new string with trailing characters removed, it doesn’t modify the original string in place. You need to assign the result back to the variable. Try this:

```
lines = readFile.readlines()

for i in range(len(lines)):
    lines[i] = lines[i].rstrip('\n')

if lines[127] == "<th>FID</th>":
    print(lines[127] + " is equal to <th>FID</th>")
else:
    print(lines[127] + " is not equal to <th>FID</th>")
```

This will ensure that each line in the lines list has its trailing newline character removed.

Comment: side note : instead of `range` over `len()` you could use python built-in function `enumerate`. ex: `for index, element in enumerate(lines) :  lines[index] = element.rstrip("\n")` (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)